# Rails API - No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I am experimenting the Rails API with devise.
I am trying to create a POST request so that the user can autenticate using the email and password. To do so, I am using `devise` and `simple token authentication`

However, when I submit my POST request using postman, I get the error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/v1/sessions"):

I think the issue is that is sending the post to: `/v1/sessions` rather than `api/v1/sessions`.

However, I do not understand why since I declared my routes such as: api-->v1-->sessions

**Folder structure of controller**

[image]

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # devise_for :users
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
    if user&.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render json: user.as_json(only: [:email, :authentication_token]), status: :created
    else
      head(:unauthorized)
    end
  end

  def destroy

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shoud it be class `Api::V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController` instead?

Comment: Thanks. That was a problem.
In addition, I was using postman on the wrong url. I was using `localhost:3000/v1/` instead of `localhost:3000/api/v1/`